# Apple M1 Two Thunderbolt Displays

Tags: thunderbolt-display, apple-silicon

I understand that there is no current workaround known for having two Apple Thunderbolt Displays run on an Apple Silicon Mac with a M1 Processor. I am opening this thread for creative solutions. Please let me know if you find a way to make this work - whether through a dock, or daisy chaining, or a Blackmagic HDMI/Thunderbolt converter. Thanks!

Comment: https://www.macrumors.com/2020/11/24/m1-macs-able-to-run-six-external-displays/

Comment: I’m going to send this as a duplicate. The M1 gear is all the same. Officially you get two displays but unofficially, they can run 5 or more large displays with third party software and adapters.